# how to add directive to d3 library in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, angular-directive

i trying to add a perfectScrollBar directive to d3 library
doing something like this

```
svg.attr('perfectScrollBar', '')
```

bit its not working.
can anyone please give me example how u add directive in d3 library?

Comment: 'not working': what's not working?

Comment: its not adding perfectScrollBar to my container

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

mb it helps someone. I found another solution

use new PerfectScrollBar after your div container is initialized

in my case i add it when mouse entered this container

```
//'this' is html div container, scrollbar is a variable to have possibility update 
//PerfectScrollBar
    function onMouseEnter() {
                    if (!scrollBar) {
                        scrollBar = new PerfectScrollbar(this, {
                            wheelPropagation: false
                        });
                    } else {
                        scrollBar.update();
                    }
                }
```